# Rename the [hoc] tag to [higher-order-component] or [react-higher-order-component]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

As [hoc] is an abbreviation, I suggest to rename it.

Comment: We already have [tag:react-hoc], and using [hoc] as a synonym isn't a good idea

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I was not aware of [react-hoc]. But shouldn't the [hoc] tag be removed and merged into [react-hoc]?

Comment: Really depends on what you mean by "merged into"; if you mean a synonym, no. `hoc` is far too generic. I also retagged all the [tag:hoc] questions to [tag:react-hoc] already

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine With 'merge' I indeed meant 'to retag'. Thank you!

Comment: A punny title could include *"[ad hoc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad_hoc#Adjective)"*.